# The JasperReports report not popping up in Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports, ireport

I integrated JasperReports in my springMVC website.
It was running fine in my local system but when I upload that website to server report is getting generated but it is not popping up as it was popping up in my local system.

I'm using iReport 4.1

Before uploading website I also change path for report.
Report is generated at destination folder but it is not displayed automatically.

This is my code:

```java
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\CallCenterRev\\reports\\AttendanceReport.jrxml");
//JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("D:\\reports\\test.jasper", jasperParameter, rsss);
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, jasperParameter, rsss);
//JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint,true);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\CallCenterRev\\reports\\AttendanceReport.pdf");
//        new mainpage(getTitle());

if ((new File("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\CallCenterRev\\reports\\AttendanceReport.pdf")).exists()) {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\CallCenterRev\\reports\\AttendanceReport.pdf");
    p.waitFor();
```

Comment: This code is executed on server. What are your waiting for this code: `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler C:\\AttendanceReport.pdf");`?

Comment: By the way, the `iReport` is GUI report's template designer for JasperReports.

Comment: ya i know but i guess Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler C:\\AttendanceReport.pdf"); itself is not running on server. i checked that report is getting generated but its is not opening form give code.

Answer (score 1):

First  why you are using absolute path.I think you should use relative path (ServletContext.getRealPath()). 
     Second ,What is for this code

```
Process p = Runtime
       .getRuntime()
       .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\CallCenterRev\\reports\\AttendanceReport.pdf");
    p.waitFor();
```

It will not show in web browser ofcourse.For viewing report in browser write pdf to http servletresponse and set http headers accordingly.

Comment: this code is for opening file from given location.
The generated pdf is stored in this location so i have specified this path here.

Comment: now i am trying to open that pdf in my web browser but here it is not opening in new tab any idea how to open that in new tab???

Comment: rushik  you missing some think browser and server are different machines.Code you  write open pdf in server not  in browser.This example show how to download file in spring MVC .(http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4629)

Comment: For opening in new tab you should export  report as  html or xhml Adn write output to  response.

Comment: got the solution..
issue was when i was deploying WAR file on server the webcontent folder was not getting generated so i was getting file not find exception.
and then i removed that folder form path and started working....

Answer (score 0):

If u r using spring 3 this might help

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/report")
    public class ReportsController
    {
        @RequestMapping(value="/getMyReport", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public void runReport(@RequestParam("someParam")String someParam,@RequestParam("someOtherParam")String someOtherParam,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        {
            InputStream is = null ;
            is = request.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/reports/myReport.jasper");
            Map paramMap = new HashMap();
            paramMap.put("someParam", someParam);
            paramMap.put("someOtherParam", someOtherParam);
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=myReport.pdf");
            try {
                Connection connection =getDatabaseConnection();//let this method returns a database connection
                JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(is, response.getOutputStream(), paramMap, connection);
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
                response.getOutputStream().close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               //may be some Exception handling

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: got the solution.. issue was when i was deploying WAR file on server the webcontent folder was not getting generated so i was getting file not find exception. and then i removed that folder form path and started working....